# how to create auto paste in script bash with touch?

Tags: bash

I want to make automatically fill the text file that I made but I don't know how, I want to make a .sh script to work automatically but I don't know how. the script that I have thought of for example like this

```
touch " ubuntu story "
```

after this I want to fill in the text in my story file, for example the text you want to add like this

```
Ubuntu is one of the most secure operating systems around. And the long-term support releases give you five years of security patches and updates.

Developer = Canonical Ltd.
OS family = Linux
Working state = Current
Source model = Open-source[1][2]
Initial release = 20 October 2004 (15 years ago)
```

how to addin this text to file ubuntu story with script ?

if using the manual method I can use this method

```
nano "ubuntu story"
```

after that I paste in the terminal column, then I `Ctrl + X + Y + Enter`, after that it will be saved.

please help me if you use the bash .sh script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *here document*

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > "ubuntu story" <<\EOF
Ubuntu is one of the most secure operating systems around. And the long-term support releases give you five years of security patches and updates.

Developer = Canonical Ltd.
OS family = Linux
Working state = Current
Source model = Open-source[1][2]
Initial release = 20 October 2004 (15 years ago)
EOF
```

Quoting of any part of the word `EOF` either as `\EOF` or `'EOF'` for example prevents shell expansion of the contents.

I used a bash shebang since that's what you tagged your question, but here documents are supported in all POSIX shells.

Comment: great, it work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In some of my scripts I do something like this:

```
touch ~/Templates/"untitled_document"


LOG=/var/log/backup.log
echo "* $(date -R) *" >> $LOG
```

Or:

```
fname=/etc/fstab
str1="# Entry for /dev/sdb6 :"
echo $str1 >> $fname
```

Note that one > overwrites or creates new file and >> adds to end of file. I have additional data I add to log file. Also better with Linux to use CamelCase, under_score or justonename rather than spaces. You have to escape spaces in future commands which makes it more complicated.