# How do I create a file in a directory and add multiple lines?

Tags: bash, gnome-shell

I want to write a script that creates a file say /usr/local/etc/new-me.txt (if it doesn't exist), add the following lines and save:

> ```
> wakeup before 6am
> sing praises
> work out 30 minutes
> take a shower
> skip breakfast
> ```

I also want to replace the file if it exist.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is not the right location for a personal to-do list

Comment: FWIW you may find a *here document* to be useful - see for example [how to create auto paste in script bash with touch?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245796/178692)

Comment: yes I just used it as example. I am working on many systems and need to manually create a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ and add many lines of code. Just looking for a way of automating that task

Comment: Then you should create the file locally and copy it to those systems instead. Or use something like Ansible or Puppet.

Comment: I think creating the file locally and copying it to the location using a script is fine.